# how to disable all notifications from windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, notifications

I have online exams for a week. The department uses a system called Wheebox https://wheebox.com/
department have sent us email  to turn of all notifications from computers.

Any pop up notification on system during exam will be taken as a noise.Meaning improper attempt to cheat in exam. Also they have mentioned in email system is very sensitive to sound and they may take the sound of any kind as voilation of fair practise.
So I want to disable any kind of notification and noise. How can I do so .

I am using Windows 10.

Comment: If your department is demanding such onerous exam conditions they should provide instructions to the students. Not providing such instructions is unfair to students who are not so computer literate.

Comment: And what happens if a noise *does* occur in the background, such as a noisy vehicle or dish being dropped? The danger of shutting *all* notificatio9sns, BTW, is no warning from your AV suite of malware being installed.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik that kind of sound is also marked by system as cheating and  I have been looking how completely stop audio from laptop. This thing which you pointed out is my concern. Some guest coming at home and pressing door bell or some vendor selling vegetables, some construction work happening near my house the sound of machines all that is big disturbance for me and system marks these sounds as cheating attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Go to System, Notifications , and turn off all the Notifications. Because some vendors have their own notifications, you need to do this now, monitor Notifications that come up and disable these. The step above will get most of them.

Also, day of exam, turn your Sound off (mute) temporarily.

[image]